# Identify clusters of identical values in column of 1s and 0s

Tags: r

This is possibly a silly question, but I am a beginner and I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere else.

Given the column in the example below, is there a way for R to automatically identify clusters of 1s and 0s, so that I can easily count how many there are in total (in this case, three clusters of 1s and three clusters of 0s)?

Thank you in advance.

```
> my_column = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0))
> my_column
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    1
 [3,]    1
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    1
 [6,]    0
 [7,]    0
 [8,]    0
 [9,]    0
[10,]    1
[11,]    1
[12,]    1
[13,]    0
[14,]    0
[15,]    0
[16,]    0
[17,]    0
[18,]    1
[19,]    1
[20,]    1
[21,]    1
[22,]    1
[23,]    1
[24,]    0
[25,]    0
[26,]    0
```

Comment: check out the ````rle()```` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try giving groups for each row. An easy way is to find the point of change. To do this, simply calculate the difference between the entry `i` and `i + 1` and take the absolute value. After that, you only need to use the `cumsum` function to create an id for each group:

```
my_column = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
new_column <- abs(c(0, my_column[-length(my_column)] - my_column[-1]))
groups <- cumsum(new_column)

my_mat <- cbind(original = my_column, new_column = new_column, group = groups)
> my_mat
        new_column  group
 [1,] 1          0      0
 [2,] 1          0      0
 [3,] 1          0      0
 [4,] 1          0      0
 [5,] 1          0      0
 [6,] 0          1      1
 [7,] 0          0      1
 [8,] 0          0      1
 [9,] 0          0      1
[10,] 1          1      2
[11,] 1          0      2
[12,] 1          0      2
[13,] 0          1      3
[14,] 0          0      3
[15,] 0          0      3
[16,] 0          0      3
[17,] 0          0      3
[18,] 1          1      4
[19,] 1          0      4
[20,] 1          0      4
[21,] 1          0      4
[22,] 1          0      4
[23,] 1          0      4
[24,] 0          1      5
[25,] 0          0      5
[26,] 0          0      5
```

Now you have everything you need.

## EDIT:

To count the number of groups you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data.frame(original = my_column, new_column = new_column, group = groups)

my_df %>% group_by(original) %>% summarise(n_groups = n_distinct(group))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  original n_groups
     <dbl>    <int>
1        0        3
2        1        3
```

Comment: Not your downvoter, but `new_column <- abs(c(0, diff(my_column)))` is a bit nicer

Comment: Since OP wants to count the number of clusters, I'd recommend leading with that, instead of putting it at the very bottom. Maybe create your grouping column in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is the one that worked best for my needs

Answer (score 4):

We can use `rle` and `table`:

```
table(rle(my_column[,1])$values)
```

**Output:**

```
0 1 
3 3
```

Answer (score -2):

You can count the 0's and ones of any column like this

```
Count_0 <- sum(my_column[,1] == 0)
Count_1 <- sum(my_column[,1] == 1)
```

Or use `apply` over the whole dataframe

Comment: Not your downvoter, but the question asks to "*identify clusters of 1s and 0s, so that I can easily count how many there are in total (in this case, three clusters of 1s and three clusters of 0s)*". This answer does nothing with clusters (by which OP seems to mean consecutive runs). Just counting 1s and 0s is a different question.OP is looking for the result "3 clusters of 1s, 3 clusters of 0s". Your result is "14 1s, 12 0s".

Comment: Definitely I can always modify the answer to help if be reasoned, how will I know unless I get the feedback

Comment: Not your downvoter, sorry, but thanks for the answer